# Drawing on UIImage gives memory warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, drawing

```
- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:drawableView];

  if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    _prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
  }

  if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
      [self drawLine:_prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
  }
  _prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}

-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to
{
  CGSize size = drawableView.frame.size;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  [drawableView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

  CGFloat strokeWidth = 4.0;
  UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);
  CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);


  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  drawableView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

I am using the above piece of code to draw on an Image present inside an UIImageView but it keeps giving me memory warning what is wrong with the code?

I have added an imageview over my imageview that contains an image and then once the user is clicks on done I build the image by drawing my drawable imageview image in the given imageview.

Answer (score 0):

The first time I read your question, I knew there was a leak in your code, since it uses Graphics - not sure about this. I only have 7 months of experience in iOS. The problem should be in your drawableView.image. You're trying to get **UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()**.

Try wrapping your code in autoreleasepool.

```
@autoreleasepool {
 // Wrap your code here...
}
```

And lastly, make sure you're running your code in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // dispatch in main!
});
```